# Hide application windows

Tags: c#, process

I try to execute process from my c# application.
The process has window. I want to hide it. If someone will search that process in the Task Manager, he will find it. But the process window will not be shown.
I tried the next code (I changed the process to the Windows Calculator to show simple to my case):

```
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);



    private void CreateHiddenProcess()
    {
       Process process;
       process = new Process();
       process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-calc_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_c52684c687eb7360\calc.exe";
       process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

       process.Start();
   
       Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
       var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Calculator");
       processes.ToList().ForEach(p =>
       {
           ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
       });
    }
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. The problem was that I didn't hold the right process.
My final working code:

```
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    public static void Hide(string processTitleName)
    {
        var pPointer = FindWindow(null, processTitleName);
        ShowWindow(pPointer, SW_HIDE);
    }
```